# Invalid arguments when creating new datalab instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am following the quickstart tutorial for datalab [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs), within the GCP console. When I try to run

```
datalab beta create-gpu datalab-instance-name
```

In step 3 I receive the following error

```
write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Can anyone help explain why this is the case and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart), before running Datalab instance, the corresponding APIs should be enabled: Google Compute Engine and Cloud Source Repositories APIs. To do so, visit `Products` -> `APIs and Services` -> `Library` and search for the APIs. Additionally, make sure that billing is enabled for your Google Cloud project.

You can also enabling the APIs by typing the following command, which will give you a prompt to enable the API:

```
datalab list
```

I made some research and found that the same issue has been reported on the [Github page](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/2157). If enabling API's wouldn't work, the best option would be to contribute (add a comment) in the mentioned Github topic to make it more visible to the Datalab Engineering team.

Comment: thanks, I had enabled the compute engine API but on the wrong project!

Comment: Update - same error just further down the pipeline after I have selected the region - will take this over to GitHub and chase up there

Comment: Please, restart the shell after enabling the APIs. Otherwise, contribute to the Github issue page.